# is it ever possible for a sequence of real-valued smooth, non-diffeomorphic functions in $\mathbb{R}$ to jump across a repulsive fixed-point?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fixed-point-iteration, banach-fixed-point

Let's say we have a real-valued smooth function $f(x)$, not diffeomorphic, which has an attractive fixed-points at  $x=3$ and $x=5$ and a repelling fixed-point at $x=4$ . Is it possible that any sequence of iterated compositions of $f(x)$ could converge to $x=5$ if started from a point $y<3$ ?

Comment: Do you require $f(x)$ to be a diffeomorphism or just a smooth function?

Comment: just smooth, not diffeomorphic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

============================================